# data-filter gallery - need active specific category not all

Tags: javascript, wordpress, themes

I have one question, in a code I have

```
<!--Filter-->
            <div class="filters">
                <ul class="filter-tabs clearfix anim-3-all">

                    <li class="filter" data-role="button" data-filter="all"><?php esc_html_e('All', 'dreamland');?></li>

                    <?php foreach( $fliteration as $t ): ?>
                    <li class="filter" data-role="button" data-filter=".<?php echo dreamland_set( $t, 'slug' ); ?>"><?php echo dreamland_set( $t, 'name'); ?></li>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Now, I have active filter "all", but how can I make active another filter? For example my category? I think, that must set up in javascript, but dont know where.

Thank you for help.

Comment: You can use get parameter for cat id then you refresh page make new query with this cat id and listing post from this category

Comment: Thank you for help, but can you explain more? For example on code what I published?

Comment: View this http://codepad.org/OvgIy2qn .. text back if you have problems

Comment: I put code into the theme and its called error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_all_fliteration() in /home/xz004800/www_root/wp-content/themes/dreamland/includes/modules/shortcodes/gallery_fullwidth.php on line 82 // Sorry Im amateur

Comment: This function must be return all $fliteration if not set get parameter. Please declared functions `get_all_fliteration` and `get_fliteration_by_cat_id($cat_id)`. Fisrt one returl all elements, second one return all elements from this category.

Comment: Understand, maybe my mistake is in wrong writing category? Please check http://codepad.org/7BahbHSB

Comment: Url request is invalid at this line `data-filter=".spevnene-plochy<?php echo $cat_id; ?>"` you can set get parameter like `/spevnene-plochy?NameOfParam<?php echo $cat_id; // this is a value - cat ID; ?>` . For example - - http://codepad.org/zhwsP4Yw

Comment: Still dont know :( this is URL of the category which I want to be active edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=gallery_category&tag_ID=26&post_type=bunch_gallery&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit-tags.php%3Ftaxonomy%3Dgallery_category%26post_type%3Dbunch_gallery

Comment: Please post  or send me all functionality and i will help you.

Comment: This is full code of galery-width page http://codepad.org/12OgxJn9 and this is galerry page which is not working https://www.laraservis.sk/galeria/

Comment: So first remove previous code like `$fliteration = get_fliteration_by_cat_id($_GET['cat_26']);` after that you must filtering well you populate array `$fliteration` so you must added `if contition` `isset($_GET['cat_26']) && $_GET['cat_26']` if this is `true` added element to array only on this term.

Comment: Can you show me on example what I send you? here -> codepad.org/12OgxJn9